# Can WGS84 results be converted to NAD83 in form?

Tags: javascript, html, gps

I have an HTML5 form that uses the geolocator script to populate text boxes with lat/long & elevation from the tablet GPS. The data is return using WGS84 datum but the database used to store the form data requires NAD83 datum.

Is there a script that will convert the default WGS84 data to NAD83 prior to populating the fields or does all the data have to be post-processed?

```
<fieldset>
   <div> Latitude: <input type="text" id="lat" name="lat" ></div>
  <div>Longitude: <input type="text" id="long" name="long" value=""></div>
  <div><label><input type="text" id="acc" name="long" value="" data-mini="true"></label>
<button onclick="getLocationConstant()" value="Get Location" data-mini="true"></button>   
 </div>

 <script>
 function getLocationConstant()
 {
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError);  
} else {
    alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
}
 }

 // If we have a successful location update
 function onGeoSuccess(event)
 {
document.getElementById("lat").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
document.getElementById("long").value = event.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById("height").value = event.coords.altitude;
document.getElementById("acc").value = event.coords.accuracy +"% accuracy";

 }

 // If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
 function onGeoError(event)
 {
alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
 }

 </script>

        <div>Elevation: <input type="text" name="height" id="height"></div>
 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula to transform between different datums or projections is too complex.

There is an open source project Proj4(javascript version) can do every thing you want about map projection. You can get it from:

http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/